# why does get_option( 'home' ) not work while using in plugin

Tags: plugin-development, options

I'm working on a wordpress plugin and am running into an inssue with `get_option( 'home' )`.

What I'm trying to do: if the user (or admin) is not logged in then a login form will appear on a custom page I've built (from the plugin). I had tried doing this from scratch but everything I was finding was telling how to do it from in the root theme folder... if anyone can help me do this (from scratch) from within a plugin I'm willing to try!

Here is my source code...

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content" class="inner">

    <div class="full shadow photo-uploadr">

        <div class="pad">

           <?php if ( is_user_logged_in()) { ?> 

            <?php } else { ?>

                <!-- BEGIN #login_form -->              
                <form name="loginform" id="login_form" class="login_form wpcf7-form" action="<?php get_option( 'home' ); ?>/wp-login.php" method="post">

                    <p>
                        <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" placeholder="Username" />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" placeholder="Password" />
                    </p>

                    <button name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="btn wpcf7-submit"><?php _e("Sign in", "shorti"); ?></button>

                </form>
                <!-- END #contact_form -->

            <?php } ?>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is from a custom page template file that the plugin has created.

The problem I'm having is when I go to sign in I'm redirected to a 404 error page saying, "url can't be found"... the reason for this is that it's only looking for `/wp-login.php`. I'm new to working with plugins... so it might be just a simple path defining issue or something noobish like that.

My plugin folder looks something like this: photo-uploadr (main folder)/photo-uploadr.php (main file)/templates (secondary folder)/custom-uploadr.php (file with issue)

Thanks & if you see anything that might not be best practice, let me know. ;)

Comment: You're new to PHP as well? Try `echo`...

Comment: Thanks @kaiser, I used 'action="<?php echo esc_url( wp_login_url() ); ?>"' like suggested below and it does exactly what I need it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_option()` **returns** a string, it doesn’t print anything. You have to use `echo` or `print`.

But you should use `home_url()` instead, because this takes care of the proper scheme (`http` or `https`):

```
echo esc_url( home_url() );
```

Or, in case of the log in URL:

```
echo esc_url( wp_login_url() );
```

Comment: So, you're saying to do something like...

    action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() '/wp-login.php' ); ?>

Comment: @Designer17 See my update, I missed the log in part.

Comment: ah, nvm just figured it out. ;)

    action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/wp-login.php" ?>

Thanks for the SUPER-FAST help... I'll be sure to come here when I REALY get stuck.

Comment: @Designer17 No, `wp-login.php` is not always the URL to log in. That’s just the default, it can be customized.

Comment: As Toscho edited his answer: there's a [`wp_login_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url) for that.

Comment: @toscho thanks. How would I set this up to login and stay on the page (showing new content through AJAX) instead of redirecting to the dashboard?

Comment: @Designer17 The AJAX part is worth a new question. But search on our site before you ask. :)